# How could I keep the data frame when working with shape files in R?

Tags: r

I'm working with two shapes and I want to get the first clean overlap with the second. To do this, I make the difference with `rgeos :: gDifference ()` and it works correctly. The first shape is a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` and the second is a `SpatialPolygons`. As a result I need a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, but I get a `SpatialPolygon`.

I have not yet found a way to correct this. Does anyone know a solution?
My script is:

```
ID <- as.character(shape_1@data$ID)

shape.gDiff <- gDifference(shape_1, shape_2, byid=T, id=ID)
```

Comment: Do you just want to convert a ```SpatialPolygon``` to ```SpatialPolygonDataFrame```? In which case: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61633/convert-a-spatial-polygon-object-to-data-frame-using-r#61636

Comment: Thank you @David Pell, finally it's help a lot